# In eclipse showing response from url

Tags: java, android

I am very new to programming and with alot of help from people on this site I have been able to make alot of progress. This time I am kinda stuck - I have been able to make a login screen and make a call but nothing shows back once the call is made.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it, again I am very new so, please, any additional code would help. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Loginretrieve extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = "http://beatswith.us/login.php";

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {

        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        Object responseString = getResponseString(response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static String getResponseString(HttpResponse response)
        throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

    String responseString = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        responseString = sb.toString();

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return responseString;
}
}
```

Comment: At the end of getResponseString method (before return statement), add System.out and print 'responseString'. Which should give you response string.

Comment: Try logging using `Log.d("tag",response)` format in your try block to log response and responseString and check what's output there(in logcat window)...

Comment: So im not getting any errors in my log cat at all Its just not displaying anything on the screen just comes back black

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error messages in your logcat?

That could definitely help in determining the problem. You could be missing the USES_PERMISSION INTERNET, or depending on the version of android you are using, it could be from trying to do network calls on the UI Thread, or a number of other problems.

Also, if you want to print to a console, do it to the logCat with:

```
Log.d("YourAppTag", "Output");
```

Which will then show up in the logcat much like the Console in regular java applications.

Edit: If you're not sure how to get to the logcat, in Eclipse go to Window->Show View->Other. Then under android pick Logcat.

Comment: So im not getting any errors in my log cat at all Its just not displaying anything on the screen just comes back black